# Why is it possible to access members of a nested static class?

Tags: java, encapsulation, static-members, nested-class

I have a nested static class named Adjudicator (don't ask ... I had named it a bit whimsically before I had read about the Builder Pattern in Effective Java) which is a builder, i.e. Client.Adjudicator builds Client objects.

Like the builder that Joshua Bloch gives as an example in Effective Java, it builds objects of the "enclosing" class (static nested classes are not truly enclosed) by invoking the enclosing class's constructor.  My class looks like this:

```
public class Client extends DB {

    private IntegerProperty id =         new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private LongProperty    defmrnKey =  new SimpleLongProperty();
    private StringProperty  lastName =   new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty  midName =    new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty  firstName =  new SimpleStringProperty();
    private IntegerProperty doB =        new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private StringProperty  gender =     new SimpleStringProperty();

    :
    :

    Client(Client cli) {  // Copy constructor

        this.id.set(cli.getID());
        this.defmrnKey.set(cli.getDefMRNKey());
        this.lastName.set(cli.getLastName());
        this.midName.set(cli.getMidName());
        this.firstName.set(cli.getFirstName());
        this.doB.set(cli.getDoB()); 
        this.gender.set(cli.getGender());
    }

    Client(Client.Adjudicator ad) {  // Invoked by builder

        this.id.set(ad.m_id);
        this.defmrnKey.set(ad.m_defmrnkey);
        this.lastName.set(ad.m_ln);
        this.midName.set(ad.m_mn);
        this.firstName.set(ad.m_fn);
        this.doB.set(ad.m_dob); 
        this.gender.set(ad.m_gen);
    }

    :
    :

    public static class Adjudicator {


        private int     m_id               = DB.KEY_UNDEFINED;
        private long    m_defmrnkey        = DB.KEY_UNDEFINED;
        private String  m_ln               = null;
        private String  m_mn               = null;
        private String  m_fn               = null;
        private int     m_dob              = DB.KEY_UNDEFINED;
        private String  m_gen              = null;

        :
        :

        public Client build() {

            // Invariants all checked here; if ok then...

            return new Client(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The static nested class is, from the point of view of the JVM, a top-level class and so instances of it don't depend on any instance of Client.

And yet, my Client class is able to freely access the private members of its builder class ... even though they're private and in a separate top-level class.

Why does this work?  Doesn't this break encapsulation?  I'm happy that this works, but this is not intuitive to me.

Comment: Never mind.  I see the answer now as soon as I posted the question.  It isn't the class that it is accessing the nested class; that is the wrong way to look at this.  The constructor in Client is passed an instance of the builder.  The access level of the builder is public ... even so, though, the members are explicitly declared with private access.  So why can the constructor access them through the passed reference?

Comment: It's sort of like package level methods and variables. The classes in the same package can access each other's. Classes outside that package can not. In this case, `private`, the scope isn't the package but the compilation unit (or call it the 'file' or the 'outer class').

Comment: @Nealon, a nested static class is just like a top-level class.  Just like one.  You can create instances of a nested static class just as you would any other top-level class and pass references of those instances.  You can't think of static classes the exact same way you would think of static fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The static nested class is, from the point of view of the JVM, a top-level class

Not exactly as you've found out. The scope of a private member is the top-level enclosing class. In your case, it is the whole `Client` class.

Note that it works both ways and your `Adjudicator` class can access the private members of your `Client` class too.

Reference: [JLS #6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> if the member is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class that encloses the declaration of the member

Comment: "Note that it works both ways and your Adjudicator class can access the private members of your Client class too."  This can't possibly be true, can it?  Instances of the Client.Adjudicator class can exist even if there are no instances of Client at all.

Comment: If you create or access an instance of Client in Adjudicator you will be able to access its private instance members. And without an instance you could access its private static members.

Comment: There seems to be a distinction here between scope and access-level that I hadn't thought about before.  Nested member classes are considered by the JVM to be in the same scope as the outer class, even if member access-levels would otherwise make those members inaccessible.  I did note with some interest that the JVM is doing something behind the scenes to make this access possible ... the Client constructor gains access to the Adjudicator fields through some facility called WriteObject()....